# Use GREP for italic Old Style Figures in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

When typsetting books, I often use GREP to locate all digits in a book and convert them to a character style for old stye figures.

But I also need to find italic digits already given an italic character style, and convert them to an italic old style figures character style.

Can GREP be used to find one character style and change it to another in an instance like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add formatting options to your find criteria, but these are specified in the lower portion of the find dialog, not in GREP.